# Include TestData.xlsx (External Excel file) into jar file while creating jar file for a Maven Project.(Windows 10 64bit, Eclipse Oxygen)

Tags: java, excel, maven, executable-jar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voouD.png) I am able to create jar file with dependencies. Normally Framework is executing good but while running jar file, I am getting error saying cannot find excel file. I have data available in excel file.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lJkv.png)

Refer the screenshot.

Comment: Really using Eclipse Oxygen? (From 2017!!) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software) upgrade your IDE....

Comment: Am I facing this issue due to IDE?

Comment: First try to build the application on plain command line..

Comment: In Plain command line, I am able to build and run the test successfully.

Comment: So this makes it clear it's an issue in your IDE either configuration of whatever....

Comment: I am facing same issue in latest version of eclipse(2021-03 released in March 2021)